# Uniform Boundedness of a $C_0$-group

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators, transport-equation

Let $p\in [1,\infty)$. On $X=L^p(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{C}^2)$ we consider the operator $D=A+B$, where

$A=\begin{pmatrix}-\partial_x & 0 \\ 0 & \partial_x \end{pmatrix}\quad{and}\quad  B=c(x)\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

(with domain $\mathsf{Dom}(D)=W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{C}^2)$). Here, $c\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a real-valued $L^\infty$-function. My question is:

Does $D$ generate a bounded $C_0$-group on $X$?

My thoughts so far:

It is clear that $A$ generates a bounded $C_0$-group on $X$. In fact,

$(e^{tA}f)(x)=\begin{pmatrix} f_1(x-t)\\ f_2(x+t)\end{pmatrix}$ for a.e. $x\in \mathbb{R}$, all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and all $f=(f_1,f_2)\in X$,

from which we immediately get that $(e^{tA})_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ is a $C_0$-group of contractions on $X$.

Now, as $B$ is bounded linear operator on $X$, it follows from standard pertubation theory that $D$ is the generator of a $C_0$-group $(e^{tD})_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$. However, pertubation theory only guarantees a growth rate $\omega\geq 0$ and and $M\geq 1$ such that $\|e^{tD}\|\leq Me^{\omega |t|}$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and this $\omega$ can be strictly positive in general (consider for example the case where $B$ was the identity matrix). So, the question is if $\omega$ can be chosen to be zero, and this seems to be a much more delicate matter.

If $f=(f_1,f_2)\in \mathsf{Dom}(D)$, then $(u,v)(t):=e^{tD}f$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$ solves the abstract Cauchy problem

$(\ast) \begin{cases}
u'(t)=-\partial_x u(t)+cv(t) \quad (t\in \mathbb{R}), \quad u(0)=f_1,\\
v'(t)=\hphantom{-}\partial_x u(t)-cu(t) \quad (t\in \mathbb{R}), \quad v(0)=f_2.
\end{cases}
$

The boundedness of $(e^{tD})_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ is then equivalent to the existence of $M\geq 1$ such that the estimate

$\|(u,v)(t)\|_{X}\leq M \|(f_1,f_2)\|_X$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$

holds. The problem is that I am not able to find any reasonable representation of the solution of $(\ast)$ which allows me estimate its $X$-norm in an effective way. Here, the problem is that $(\ast)$ is coupled (it is a coupled system of transport equations) and that $c$ is only asssumed to be $L^\infty$ which makes taking one additional time derivative in order to obtain a decoupled wave equation problematic.

My hope is that $(e^{tD})_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ is indeed bounded, and if not I am curious to know if it is possible to give (smallness-)conditions on $c$ that make the $C_0$-group bounded.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the case $p=2$, $(e^{tD})$ is a unitary group, hence is a bounded $C_0$-group. For other values of $p$, I have no definite answer. Also, note that $(e^{tA})$ is **not** a contraction for $p\neq 2$, whereas $(e^{tB})$ satisfies $\|e^{tB}\|=1$ regardless of the value of $p$. This is quite unfortunate, because if $(e^{tA})$ were also a contraction group, then we would have been able to invoke Trotter product formula to show $(e^{tD})$ is bounded.

Comment: I had the equivalent norm $\|f\|_X=\|f_1\|_p+\|f_2\|_p$ for $f=(f_1,f_2)\in X$ in mind. Then $\|e^{tA}f\|_X=\|f\|_X$, thus $e^{tA}$ is a contraction with respect to this norm. If I am not mistaken, also $e^{tB}$ is a contractions with respect to this norm. I am not familiar with the Trotter product formula. I'll have a look into that. Thanks!

Comment: @SangchulLee I just had a look. If $A$ and $B$ are generators of contractions, so is $A+B$, and therefore I would be done. Correct?

Comment: Ah, I see. My comment about non-contractibility is based on the version $$\|\mathbf{f}\|_{L^p}=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \|\mathbf{f}(x)\|_2^p \, \mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}$$ where $\|(z_1,z_2)\|_2=\sqrt{|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2}$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{C}^2$. Now I agree that $e^{tA}$ is a contraction with respect to your version of $L^p$-norm, but I haven't checked if $e^{tB}$ is a contraction w.r.t. this norm. But if that is indeed the case, then your reasoning would be correct :)

Comment: Unfortunately, matters are more subtle than I thought: $e^{tA}$ is a contraction with respect to $\|\cdot\|_X$, but not with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{L^p}$ and with $e^{tB}$ it is the other way around. However, I still try to invoke the Trotter product formula or the Dyson-Phillips series to find conditions under which $e^{t(A+B)}$ is bounded. Anyhow, thanks for the suggestion!